# Is there any way to get editer focus back once call cell.getRow().normalizeHeight() in tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using the tabulator v4.7. I am facing an issue in editor focus when we call `cell.getRow().normalizeHeight()`

Once I call this, I need to click 2 times on the next input field to start editing.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a link to a JS Fiddle or CodePen that demonstrates your editor in action. The `normalizeHeight` action shouldnt result in a loss of focus. The built in textarea editor uses it without any issue

Comment: @OliFolkerd, it seems, we need to give height to parent div/body to make it work. I have given height: 100% to tabulator but did not set the height to parent/body. Once I had given height to parent it worked. But I can not give 100% to both parent and the table. So removed from table and added just to parent div. Not sure it is the solution but it worked for me. I am using formatter as textarea and editor as input